# Error too few arguments to function while using a friend function

Tags: c++

The question was to create a class named ACCOUNTS with a read function to accept the sales and purchases and then to create a friend function to print total tax to pay. I have tried doing this, but I keep getting the error that the funtion read and tottax have too few arguments. What can I correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class ACCOUNTS
    {   
        public:
        ACCOUNTS(){sales=0,purchase=0;}
        private:
            int sales,purchase;


        friend void tottax(ACCOUNTS &sfo);
        friend void read(ACCOUNTS &sfo);
    };
        void read(ACCOUNTS &sfo)
        {
            cout<<"Enter saleamt : \n";
            cin>>sfo.sales;
            cout<<"Enter purchaseamt : \n";
            cin>>sfo.purchase;
        }
        void tottax(ACCOUNTS &sfo)
        {
            int tax=(sfo.sales-sfo.purchase)*(4/100);
            cout<<"\nTax : "<<tax;
        }
        int main()
        {
            read();
            tottax();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Does `tottax();` match `void tottax(ACCOUNTS &sfo)`?

Comment: Yes! It does. I mean I am calling the function tottax in the main right?

Comment: `read();` also with the same problem

Comment: Where is the parameter that `tottax` wants?

Comment: I don't get it... Why does does tottax need a parameter. (I'm a beginner to Cpp and OOP concepts... Forgot to mention. My first program after attending calsses)

Comment: @MeetGujrathi `void tottax(ACCOUNTS &sfo)` says `tottax` wants a `ACCOUNTS &`.  if you don't give it one you get an error. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

`void tottax(ACCOUNTS &sfo)` says; hey, I am a function which does not return a single bit (`void` as return type), but I need an object of type `ACCOUNTS` to be called. So you either give me one, or I am not gonna execute.

In your `main` you are calling `tottax` in the following way: `tottax()`
which translates to:
Dear compiler could you please call the function tottax, the one which does not take any parameter? The compiler look at you r source code and try to find something like: `void totax(){...}` which clearly does not exists cause the only version of `tottax` **you wrote takes one and only one parameter**.

So again, the problem is that, `tottax` wants **one and only one parameter**. That is why the compiler is complaining.

Plus think about it a bit more: `tottax` computes something that is related to an `ACCOUNTS`. If you don't provide one, what is it gonna compute?

The same holds for the function `read`.